# RFT - very slow to add objects

Tags: automated-testing, rft

I'm currently exploring [RFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IBM_Rational_Functional_Tester) for my team. I have come across few issues (as per IBM help website, it's a known issue) with Java Scripting. Hence ditched it and now got .net scripting working with 2010 VS.

I'm at initial stages, trying to record few scripts and see how it works. With my experience on other tools, I was able to get this thing running.

The question here is, while trying to add an object (a link) from the application to object map, it takes like almost 5 minutes to add it to the object map. Instead of recording, I'm trying to add it by opening the object map and selecting "Test Object->Insert Objects ->Test Object Browser (as selection method).

With the application displayed on the open browser(IE8, Win-7), after selecting an object, object map window gets hanged for about 4-5 mins. then adding it to object map takes similar amount of time.

Is there anyway to speed this up? Anything missed in the process? Any suggestions on this or is this the normal setup speed in RFT? Is it suggested not to use Obj Map at all?

Comment: I've found, in general, IBM Rational products are not overly concerned with speed. My department moved away from test object maps for this and several other reasons, instead using dynamic finds (which are much faster and easier to maintain)

Answer (score 2):

Is your Win7 32bit or 64bit?

If it's 32bit you can try using JRE 6u33, RFT runs good with it. (get it here http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javasebusiness/downloads/java-archive-downloads-javase6-419409.html#jre-6u33-oth-JPR )
If it's the 64 bit version... well... I had your same issue (browser hanging for a while, IE9) and tried a lot of JRE's (32 and 64 bit) but nothing helped.
It's just unusable.

Comment: It's 64 bit. It just doesn't work. Is there any way to manually add an object and avoiding all the hassle of going through the test browser object?

Comment: No, RFT records the tree structure of the page, using the browser as the root object. But you can dynamically get objects using the `find()` method, more details here: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rational/library/06/0711_nowacki_nodwell/

Answer (score 0):

There have been many improvements over the years in the 64-bit application testing and the speeds are now comparable. However, as suggested, using the find() API to locate objects leveraging the strong scripting SDK assists in creating reusable and maintainable scripts.

Were you able to use the find() API for your scripting ?